# How to config Laravel Websockets to use to use SSL?

Tags: laravel, pusher, laravel-websockets

I have configured my Laravel websockets to use SSL, but it's giving the "Peer's certificate issuer not recognized". Here's my config files. I'll be so grateful if someone can help me.

broadcasting.php

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                'curl_options' => [
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                ]
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],
```

websockets.php

```
'ssl' => [
        /*
         * Path to local certificate file on filesystem. It must be a PEM encoded file which
         * contains your certificate and private key. It can optionally contain the
         * certificate chain of issuers. The private key also may be contained
         * in a separate file specified by local_pk.
         */
        'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

        /*
         * Path to local private key file on filesystem in case of separate files for
         * certificate (local_cert) and private key.
         */
        'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

        /*
         * Passphrase for your local_cert file.
         */
        'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
```

Comment: What cert are you using?

Comment: ssl certificate.